# Does Webpack tree-shake by default when building production React project?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm learning React and want to know if Webpack tree-shakes a React project by default when we do `npm run build` to create the production version of the project?

Comment: Here is a result of a 5 sec use of the Google search

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/dq85cq/cra_treeshaking_support_and_usage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. You can view the built application in the `build/` folder.

If you look at some of those .js files you will see they look quite different from your source contents. Your source will be tree-shaken and minified.